# What is the German term for “Financial capital”?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

I’d like to know the German term for a financial capital (city), e.g. London, Hong Kong, Frankfurt. I’d like to say:

> Frankfurt ist Europas _________ .

Comment: With *Finanzhauptstadt*, *Finanzzentrum* and *Finanzmetropole*, you’re already spoiled for choice.

Comment: Geldeneinzugszentrale

Answer (score 9):

**Finanzhauptstadt**

The complete, grammatically correct sentence would read: "Frankfurt ist die Finanzhauptstadt Europas."

(Note that you usually do not use *Europa* with an article.)

Examples of actual usage:

- ["Noch ist London die Finanzhauptstadt Europas."](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/finanzen/aktien/mit-brexit-koennte-frankfurt-finanzhauptstadt-europas-werden-14094436.html)
- ["Doch der Titel 'Finanzhauptstadt der Welt' sieht jetzt gar nicht mehr so erstrebenswert aus."](http://www.handelsblatt.com/meinung/kolumnen/london-new-york-finanzzentrum-der-welt-nein-danke/3335886.html)
- ["Finanzhauptstadt, Wirtschaftsstandort, internationaler Anziehungspunkt – die Europäische Zentralbank ist ein Pfund, mit dem Frankfurt wuchern kann."](https://www.frankfurt.de/sixcms/detail.php?id=8656&_ffmpar[_id_inhalt]=28755053)

Answer (score 8):

> Frankfurt ist das **Finanzzentrum** Europas.

The English *capital* is cognate to *Haupt-*, making *Finanzhauptstadt* a nice, literal translation, but *Finanzzentrum* is both more generic and less figuratively. The *Zentrum* is the midpoint where it all meets.

I have a feeling *-hauptstadt* is used in rather shallow or general coverage, while *-zentrum* is the actual term (the lemma, see German Wikipedia: [*Finanzplatz*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finanzplatz)).

It also depends on whether you want to put emphasis on the actual city or its role as a central place.

Also see this [Ngram of *Finanzhauptstadt* and *Finanzzentrum*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Finanzhauptstadt%2CFinanzzentrum&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CFinanzhauptstadt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CFinanzzentrum%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 4):

Another version:

> Finanzmetropole

But  [Finanzzentrum](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/29235/392) is even more common (Google: ~ 132.000 hits; Finanzmetropole: ~70.000; Finanzhauptstadt: ~3.000 - see also [this nice Google NGram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=finanzhauptstadt%2Cfinanzmetropole%2Cfinanzzentrum%2Cfinanzplatz&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CFinanzhauptstadt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CFinanzmetropole%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CFinanzzentrum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CFinanzplatz%3B%2Cc0)).

Comment: Right, you often read about *-metropole* too.